# What solar panel subsidies does Australia have right now?

Tags: australia, government, electricity, subsidy

I'm thinking about buying solar panels for my house.

Only thing is I'm not sure whether to wait.

I've been told that the value of solar power in Australia has remained largely the same - this is because as the cost of solar panels have fallen, the subsidies have been removed.

However, I'm now just wondering, what kind of subsidies are there still for solar panels? Can someone explain them? Are the government chipping in for the panels or something?

Because in Australia, you now only get 7.5 cents per kWH back to the grid whereas you buy electricity from the grid at like 25.9 cents / kWH. If anything, it seems a little unfair - it's the same energy, why is my clean energy only worth 25% of energy generated from coal?

So yeah, I guess the question is does Australia still have solar panel subsidies? If not, given that solar panel prices are getting progressively cheaper, would I be better off just waiting till the prices drop before buying?

Comment: re the grid feed-in : Because your solar is a must-take source with somewhat erratic output.  It means grid control not only has to forecast load, but also forecast generation and that they need to have more (expensive) peaking generation to backstop the solar when its output falls.  It's great from an environmental perspective, but for the people managing the grid, the uncontrollably and poor predictability of it makes their jobs harder.

Comment: Not an answer, and maybe a controversial statement, but the political wind in Australia and every other country in the world can change direction so frequently and fast that I would not count on subsidies to stay even if they show up tomorrow. I write that because solar panels are kind of a long-term investment.

Answer (score 1):

The first search on Google:
http://yourenergysavings.gov.au/rebates/renewable-power-incentives

This links to the following:
http://yourenergysavings.gov.au/energy/solar-wind-hydro-power/solar-power/install-solar-power

A quick copy/paste in case that ever gets changed:

- Electricity feed-in tariff

  - NSW, QLD, NT, SA, VIC, TAS, WA, ACT
- Renewable power incentives (solar, wind and hydro)

  - ACT, NSW, NT, QLD, SA, TAS, VIC, WA

So, from what I understand of what I can find online, yes they do still have it. But it really depends on your installation, where you live, etc.

Through this search you can find the feed-in tariff that applies for you:
https://www.energymadeeasy.gov.au/offer-search

Edit: damn, didn't notice that this question is old.